# Given a word, find the Longest Word(s) In a Dictionary that can be formed using the word passed

Tags: java, algorithm

Given a word, find the Longest Word(s) In a Dictionary that can be formed using the word.

```
public static List<String> longestWord (String word, String[] dictionary) { }
```

My approach is:

1. Find all permutations of the word
2. Match those permutations with words in the Dictionary array

Is there a better approach to this problem?

Comment: In addition, you could determine the maximum size of a word in the dictionary in order to limit the length of the permutation you want to find before.

Comment: What does "can be formed using the word" mean? Do you mean by using only the set of letters in the word? Can you reuse letters any number of time? Do you have to use all letters?

Comment: How many queries with different words do you expect? (It might be useful to pre-treat dictionary)

Comment: What do you mean by "_can be formed using the word passed_"? Because in your current approach, the permutations of the given word will always be of equal or shorter length than the output word. In that case you could check if the given `String word` is in the dictionary, and if it is, just return that.. If you mean however that using the distinct letters of the given `word`, find the longest word in the dictionary we can form using only zero or more of these letters, you won't need the permutations of the given word at all, but just check if each distinct character is in a dictionary-word.

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be a *homework*, that's why let me *not* provide the code, but the idea(s).

**First Case**

If we can use letters *partialy* e.g. **car** can be formed from **a**bra**c**dab**r**a

Turn all the words in the dictionary into a `Map<Character, Integer>` where `key` - word's character, `value` - number of occurrences.

For instance:

`"abracadabra"` should be turned into

```
  'a' : 5 // "abracadabra" contains 5 'a's 
  'b' : 2 // ..                     2 'b's
  'c' : 1 // ..                     1 'c'
  'd' : 1
  'r' : 2
```

turn the `word` into the same `Map<Character, Integer>` structure, e.g. `"arcada"` is

```
  'a' : 3
  'c' : 1
  'd' : 1
  'r' : 1
```

To test if `word1` can be formed from `word2` you should ensure that

1. Each `key` or `word1Map` appears in `word2Map`
2. Each corresponding `value` or `word1Map` is less or equal than `word2Map` value

e.g. if `word1 = "arcada"` can be formed from `words2 = "abracadabra"`?

```
 key   word1value word2value 
 'a'            3          5  3 <= 5? true 
 'c'            1          1  1 <= 1? true
 'd'            1          1  1 <= 1? true
 'r'            1          2  1 <= 2? true
 -----------------------------------------
                                      true: can be formed
```

Now a simple loop over dictionary will solve the problem

**Second Case**

If you *can't* use letters *partialy* e.g. `"car"` can be formed from `"arc"` but not from `"card"`

The algorithm is quite easy: sort all the letters within each word from the dictionary:

```
 "car"         -> "acr"
 "card"        -> "acdr"

 "abracadabra" -> "aaaaabbcdrr"

 "art"         -> "art"
 "rat"         -> "art"
 "tar"         -> "art"
```

do the same with a given `word`, e.g. `"arc" -> "acr"` and loop over the dictionary for the equal transformed word:

```
 "car" -> "acr" == "acr" (from "arc") so "car" can be formed from "arc"
```

notice that

```
 "abracadabra" -> "aaaaabbcdrr" != "acr" (from "arc")
```

so now `"arc"` can'be formed from `"abracadabra"`

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. Loop over the words in the dictionary, sort the characters of the words and remove duplicate characters.
2. Store the words in a hashmap where the key is sorted characters of the word and value is a list of words which have same unique, sorted characters.
3. While searching, sort the characters in the input word, remove the duplicates and use it as a key to search in the hashmap.
4. Find the words with maximum characters from the list.

Comment: Nice approach. Thanks! Why are we removing duplicate characters in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

We can also solve this using extra space:

First create unordered_map<char,int> ..insert all string characters in map.

Using loop for every dictionary word and check if all characters of dictionary word is exist in map or not.

If all characters exist in map than insert that dictionary word into the vector(using extra space vector of string to store the words that have same characters like string)

sort the vector according to the string length.

Below is the C++ code:

```
 bool checkAllCharacters(string s, unordered_map<char,int> mp)
   {
        int i=0;
        while(s[i]!='\0')
       {
            if(mp.find(s[i])==mp.end())
               return false;
            
            i++;
       }
    
       return true;
    }
    bool comp(string a, string b)
    {
        return a.length() > b.length();
    }

string longestWord(string s, vector<string> dict)
{
    unordered_map<char,int> mp;
    
    vector<string> matchWords;
    
    for(int i=0; i<s.length();i++)
    {
        mp[s[i]]++;
    }
    
    for(int i=0; i<dict.size(); i++)
    {
        if(checkAllCharacters(dict[i],mp))
            matchWords.push_back(dict[i]);
    }
    
    sort(matchWords.begin(), matchWords.end(), comp);
    
    return matchWords[0];
}
```

Please let me know if anything wrong or misunderstands here.

Thanks